# Challenge: Recode data from Alpha to Non sequential Numeric

Tags: r

We are looking for a blazing fast solution to the following problem, in R (Rcpp is allowed).

I have a character vector:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 1e6, replace = TRUE)
```

And I want to change it to a **non sequential numeric vector**, where:

```
A = 5
B = 4
C = 3
D = 1
```

For example:

```
c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

Would be:

```
c(5,4,3,1)
```

The interns and I have what we think is a ridiculously fast solution already but we think the Internet can beat us. We'll add our fastest solution as an answer after we get some responses.

Let's see!

Timings so far:

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(42)
x <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 1e6, replace = TRUE)

richscriven <- function(x) {
  as.vector(c(A=5, B=4, C=3, D=2, E=1)[x])
}

richscriven_unname <- function(x) {
  unname(c(A=5, B=4, C=3, D=2, E=1)[x])
}

richscriven_op <- function(x) {
  (5:1)[c(factor(x))]
}

op_and_interns_fun <- function(x) {
  c(5,4,3,1)[as.numeric(as.factor(x))]
}

ronakshah <- function(x) {
  vec = c("A" = 5, "B" = 4, "C" = 3, "D" = 1)
  unname(vec[match(x, names(vec))])
}

microbenchmark(
  richscriven_unname(x),
  richscriven(x),
  richscriven_op(x),
  op_and_interns_fun(x),
  ronakshah(x),
  times = 15
)

Unit: milliseconds
                  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 richscriven_unname(x) 36.06018 38.01026 62.80854 38.87179 41.86411 337.65773    15
        richscriven(x) 37.90615 41.61194 43.50555 44.14130 45.17277  47.47804    15
     richscriven_op(x) 31.70345 37.43262 44.10522 41.34828 45.22127  88.79605    15
 op_and_interns_fun(x) 40.18935 44.20475 49.48811 45.77867 48.15706  99.85034    15
          ronakshah(x) 29.36408 32.52615 42.40753 35.09052 38.55763  95.78571    15
```

Comment: This is not a StackOverflow question. This is a CodeReview-based question.

Comment: @Jaap this isnt a a strict letters to number as you've marked it - its non sequential if you looked closer.

Comment: Please don't add comments to your question but post them as comments. That way the user also gets pinged. If it's not a duplicate, please edit the question to explain *why* the duplicate does not answer your question.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen How is this not code review material? Your present solution was obfuscated by placing it not in the opening salvo but as an answer. If anything, this is a variety of code _golf_. The basis of the question is in getting the _fastest_ algorithm for recoding data. This sort of implies a _code review_. Anyhow, tomato tomatoe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can put the vector in a named numeric vector

```
vec <-  c("A" = 5, "B" = 4, "C" = 3, "D" = 1)
```

We can then write a function,

```
get_recoded_data <- function(num_vec, recode_data) {
   unname(recode_data[match(num_vec, names(recode_data))]) 
}
```

and call the function using

```
get_recoded_data(x, vec)
```

On my system it takes,

```
system.time(get_recoded_data(x, vec))
#user  system elapsed 
#0.028   0.004   0.032
```

I am using MacOS Sierra 10.12.6, 16GB RAM i7 RStudio 1.1.383

---

From @zacdav's comment using `fmatch` function from `fastmatch` package gives a good performance enhancement

```
get_recoded_data <- function(num_vec, recode_data) {
  unname(recode_data[fmatch(num_vec, names(recode_data))]) 
}
```

Checking it on the same data, I get

```
system.time(get_recoded_data(x, vec))
#user  system elapsed 
#0.017   0.004   0.021
```

Comment: `unname(vec[fastmatch::fmatch(x, names(vec))])`
using `fastmatch` package is a huge speed jump again.

Comment: @zacdav Thanks, didn't know about `fastmatch` package.

Comment: If you place last round bracket in another place: `unname(recode_data)[fmatch(num_vec, names(recode_data))]` then timings will become better almost twice - from 26 ms to 16 ms on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Our answer relies on a somewhat uncommon method of subsetting by position:

```
op_and_interns_fun <- function(x) {
  c(5,4,3,1)[as.numeric(as.factor(x))]
}
```

Comment: why isn't this just posted in the question? You clearly already had this solution at time of posting.

Comment: We didn't want to discourage people if our final solution was faster than theirs. I'm working with interns that I'd like to show a variety of different answers (we have about 6 other solutions that are all much slower and not shown here), you know, for learning purposes :)